Why waiting for Atlas?
In Atlas (2024), Harlan

 got liberated after scanning a young Atlas once she wore the Interlink

Why did he need to wait for this event

 and not doing this when Atlas' mother was wearing it?


Harlan persuaded Atlas to make the interlink two-way which her mother refused to do.
Only when the link was two way could Harlan scan her mind fully.

Ahhh, now I realize that the Wikipedia article also states (emphasis mine) Atlas (...)  gave Harlan an unfettered interface with her mind. This is exactly what you explained. Thanks.
